# vb.net HttpWebRequest BeginGetResponse parameters

Tags: multithreading, parameters, webrequest

I'm doing threaded webrequests. How do I pass the parameter 'index' from the Start() sub to GetResponseCallback()?

The two subs:

```
Shared Sub Start(ByVal index As Integer)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://sternbud.com/login/checklogin.php"), HttpWebRequest)

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Method = "POST"

    Debug.Print(index & ">" & AccountArray(dictThread.Keys(index)))

    Dim result As IAsyncResult = CType(request.BeginGetRequestStream(AddressOf GetRequestStreamCallback, request), IAsyncResult)

    allDone.WaitOne()
End Sub 

Private Shared Sub GetRequestStreamCallback(ByVal asynchronousResult As IAsyncResult)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(asynchronousResult.AsyncState, HttpWebRequest)

    Dim postStream As Stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult)
    Dim postData As [String] = "myusername=" & AccountArray(AccountIndex) & "&mypassword=test"


    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length)
    postStream.Close()

    Dim result As IAsyncResult = CType(request.BeginGetResponse(AddressOf GetResponseCallback, request), IAsyncResult)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass it as an `Object` in the last parameter to `BeginGetRequestStream`. Currently you have:

```
Dim result As IAsyncResult = CType(request.BeginGetRequestStream(AddressOf GetRequestStreamCallback, request), IAsyncResult)
```

You're passing the `result` in the `state` parameter, and that value gets set in the `AsyncState` property of the passed `IAsyncResult`.

If you want to pass two values, you have some choices:

1. Create a new object that has the `result` and `index` values as separate properties.
2. Create an array of `Object` where the first item is the request and the second is the index. You can then get the `AsyncState` property, case it to an object array, and peel out the items.
3. Create a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from your two values, and pass that `Tuple` in the `state` parameter.

I prefer the second because it's so easy, but creating a `Tuple` is cleaner (i.e. type-safe) and almost as easy. I have a C# example of the second method at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4555766/56778.